# Raphael.js perspective transformation

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I'm working with Raphael.js and have a problem to create a perspective transformation. It should be a svg / raphael solution, because it's one step to create an image. Here is an image how it looks now:

[image: top view]

The target is to use transform to skew it at the z-axis. It should looks like this image:

[image: target]

---

Code:

```
paper.setStart();
Obj=paper.path('M 2500 3750 L 2500 3481.9 L 0 3481.9 L 0 3750 L 2500 3750Z');
Obj.attr({'fill':field_color1,'stroke':'none', 'fill-opacity': opacity});
Obj=paper.path('M 2500 3482.2 L 2500 3214.1 L 0 3214.1 L 0 3482.2 L 2500 3482.2Z');
Obj.attr({'fill':field_color2,'stroke':'none', 'fill-opacity': opacity});
Obj=paper.path('M 2500 3214.3 L 2500 2946.2 L 0 2946.2 L 0 3214.3 L 2500 3214.3Z');
Obj.attr({'fill':field_color1,'stroke':'none', 'fill-opacity': opacity});
Obj=paper.path('M 2500 2946.5 L 2500 2678.4 L 0 2678.4 L 0 2946.5 L 2500 2946.5Z');
Obj.attr({'fill':field_color2,'stroke':'none', 'fill-opacity': opacity});
Obj=paper.path('M 2500 2678.6 L 2500 2410.6 L 0 2410.6 L 0 2678.6 L 2500 2678.6Z');
Obj.attr({'fill':field_color1,'stroke':'none', 'fill-opacity': opacity});
Obj=paper.path('M 2500 2410.8 L 2500 2142.7 L 0 2142.7 L 0 2410.8 L 2500 2410.8Z');
Obj.attr({'fill':field_color2,'stroke':'none', 'fill-opacity': opacity});
Obj=paper.path('M 2500 2142.9 L 2500 1874.9 L 0 1874.9 L 0 2142.9 L 2500 2142.9Z');
Obj.attr({'fill':field_color1,'stroke':'none', 'fill-opacity': opacity});
Obj=paper.path('M 2500 1875.1 L 2500 1607 L 0 1607 L 0 1875.1 L 2500 1875.1Z');
Obj.attr({'fill':field_color2,'stroke':'none', 'fill-opacity': opacity});
Obj=paper.path('M 2500 1607.3 L 2500 1339.2 L 0 1339.2 L 0 1607.3 L 2500 1607.3Z');
Obj.attr({'fill':field_color1,'stroke':'none', 'fill-opacity': opacity});
Obj=paper.path('M 2500 1339.4 L 2500 1071.3 L 0 1071.3 L 0 1339.4 L 2500 1339.4Z');
Obj.attr({'fill':field_color2,'stroke':'none', 'fill-opacity': opacity});
Obj=paper.path('M 2500 1071.6 L 2500 803.5 L 0 803.5 L 0 1071.6 L 2500 1071.6Z');
Obj.attr({'fill':field_color1,'stroke':'none', 'fill-opacity': opacity});
Obj=paper.path('M 2500 803.8 L 2500 535.7 L 0 535.7 L 0 803.8 L 2500 803.8Z');
Obj.attr({'fill':field_color2,'stroke':'none', 'fill-opacity': opacity});
Obj=paper.path('M 2500 535.9 L 2500 267.8 L 0 267.8 L 0 535.9 L 2500 535.9Z');
Obj.attr({'fill':field_color1,'stroke':'none', 'fill-opacity': opacity});
Obj=paper.path('M 2500 268 L 2500 0 L 0 0 L 0 268 L 2500 268Z');
Obj.attr({'fill':field_color2,'stroke':'none', 'fill-opacity': opacity});

Obj=paper.path('M 1237.1 597.3 C 1237.1 604.4 1242.9 610.2 1250 610.2 C 1257.1 610.2 1262.9 604.4 1262.9 597.3 C 1262.9 590.1 1257.1 584.4 1250 584.4 C 1242.9 584.4 1237.1 590.1 1237.1 597.3');
Obj.attr({'fill': line_color,'stroke':'none'});
Obj=paper.path('M 1262.9 3151.7 C 1262.9 3144.6 1257.1 3138.8 1250 3138.8 C 1242.9 3138.8 1237.1 3144.6 1237.1 3151.7 C 1237.1 3158.9 1242.9 3164.7 1250 3164.7 C 1257.1 3164.7 1262.9 3158.9 1262.9 3151.7');
Obj.attr({'fill': line_color,'stroke':'none'});
Obj=paper.path('...');
Obj.attr({'fill': line_color,'stroke':'none'});
var st = paper.setFinish();
```

---

EDIT: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tj9bJ/)

Is there any solution?

Comment: Could you get a test example up on a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if skewing is the answer here. The thing is that you are trying to apply a 3d effect on the paper, not a 2d one.
I'm **not** sure that it can be done in pure svg and raphael too, but here's a pure css solution using css3 3d transform (rotateX) and perspective:

```
body {
    /* the lower the value, the higher the distortion */
    perspective: 600px;
}

#raph-rotate {
    width: 500px;
    height: 750px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    transform: rotateX(30deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
}
```

Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Tj9bJ/2/

Comment: Yes, you are right. It's an perspective transform instead of skewing. I'll update my post. Your solution works fine, but i need a raphael / svg solution because the transformation is a middle step to create an image :)

Comment: Raphael and SVG are 2D technologies, neither of them will directly do the kind of transform you want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible in Raphael. A simple question though: why don't you draw it directly in the shape you want? I mean, it's not a very difficult shape to draw.

This being said, i think you should draw differently. I'd do it like this (I re-used the pathes you gave us in your "code" section):

```
var path;
var set = paper.set();
function obj(chosenPath,color){
                switch(color){

                    case 1:
                    path = paper.path(chosenPath).attr({
                        fill:field_color1,
                        stroke : "none",
                        "fill-opacity":opacity
                    });
                    break;

                    case 2:
                    path = paper.path(chosenPath).attr({
                        fill:field_color2,
                        stroke : "none",
                        "fill-opacity":opacity
                    });
                    break;

                    case 3:
                    path = paper.path(chosenPath).attr({
                        fill:line_color,
                        stroke : "none",
                    });
                    break;

                    default:
                    return hue;
                }

                set.push(path);

            }

obj('M 2500 3750 L 2500 3481.9 L 0 3481.9 L 0 3750 L 2500 3750Z',1);
obj('M 2500 3482.2 L 2500 3214.1 L 0 3214.1 L 0 3482.2 L 2500 3482.2Z',2);
obj('M 2500 3214.3 L 2500 2946.2 L 0 2946.2 L 0 3214.3 L 2500 3214.3Z',1);
obj('M 2500 2946.5 L 2500 2678.4 L 0 2678.4 L 0 2946.5 L 2500 2946.5Z',2);
obj('M 2500 2678.6 L 2500 2410.6 L 0 2410.6 L 0 2678.6 L 2500 2678.6Z',1)
obj('M 2500 2410.8 L 2500 2142.7 L 0 2142.7 L 0 2410.8 L 2500 2410.8Z',2)
obj('M 2500 2142.9 L 2500 1874.9 L 0 1874.9 L 0 2142.9 L 2500 2142.9Z',1);
obj('M 2500 1875.1 L 2500 1607 L 0 1607 L 0 1875.1 L 2500 1875.1Z',2);
obj('M 2500 1607.3 L 2500 1339.2 L 0 1339.2 L 0 1607.3 L 2500 1607.3Z',1);
obj('M 2500 1339.4 L 2500 1071.3 L 0 1071.3 L 0 1339.4 L 2500 1339.4Z',2);
obj('M 2500 1071.6 L 2500 803.5 L 0 803.5 L 0 1071.6 L 2500 1071.6Z',1);
obj('M 2500 803.8 L 2500 535.7 L 0 535.7 L 0 803.8 L 2500 803.8Z',2);
obj('M 2500 535.9 L 2500 267.8 L 0 267.8 L 0 535.9 L 2500 535.9Z',1);
obj('M 2500 268 L 2500 0 L 0 0 L 0 268 L 2500 268Z',2);
obj('M 1237.1 597.3 C 1237.1 604.4 1242.9 610.2 1250 610.2 C 1257.1 610.2 1262.9 604.4 1262.9 597.3 C 1262.9 590.1 1257.1 584.4 1250 584.4 C 1242.9 584.4 1237.1 590.1 1237.1 597.3',3);
obj('M 1262.9 3151.7 C 1262.9 3144.6 1257.1 3138.8 1250 3138.8 C 1242.9 3138.8 1237.1 3144.6 1237.1 3151.7 C 1237.1 3158.9 1242.9 3164.7 1250 3164.7 C 1257.1 3164.7 1262.9 3158.9 1262.9 3151.7',3)
```

This way you can modify every single element of your playfield within the set, and you don't need to rewrite ".attr({stuff...})" so many times.

Comment: The "code" above is generated by a tool which convert svg files to raphael code :) At the moment I only want to try some effects. Later i'll put it in pretty looking OOP style :)

Comment: I see :)
Still, I might be missing something, but why don't you try drawing it directly in the shape you want? It's quite simple in my opinion.

Comment: I want to create an image which can dynamically be changed by users. Colors, opacity and the perspective should be options.

Comment: If it turns out it's not possible to do what you want in Raphael, you could draw several versions of the playfield. This way you could limit the choice of perspective values for the user. You know, 10° per 10° in the axis you want, something like that. That's a long job to do though.